# Replace cell fill color based on existing cell fill color in a column

Tags: excel, vba, macros, background-color, cells

I have attached screenshot to visualize what I am trying to do.

[image]

I am trying to replace the fill colors of cells in a column "Yesterday" based on the existing cell fill color.

I have seen examples of replacing colors based of a value in a cell but I think I have a different scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help you:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, foundCells As Range
    Dim yesterdayColor As Long, todayColor As Long

    yesterdayColor = Range("H3").Interior.Color
    todayColor = Range("H4").Interior.Color

    With Range("B5:B17") '<--| reference wanted range of which coloring any "yesterdayColor" colored cells with "todayColor" color
        Set foundCells = .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1) '<-- initialize a dummy "found" cell outside the relevant range and avoid 'IF' checking in subsequent 'Union()' method calls
        For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through referenced range cells
            If cell.Interior.Color = yesterdayColor Then Set foundCells = Union(foundCells, cell) '<--| gather yesterday colored cells together
        Next cell
        Set foundCells = Intersect(.Cells, foundCells) '<--| get rid of the dummy "found" cell
    End With
    If Not foundCells Is Nothing Then foundCells.Interior.Color = todayColor '<--| if any cell has been found then change their color
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not to be more confusing, I have attached my actual worksheet      http://i.stack.imgur.com/BuiFc.jpg                                                            This worksheet should help me track the progress of any campaign. When I open the spreadsheet based on the date, the particular column gets highlighted. I have used conditional formatting & today() function to achieve this. The next step is to fill cell color for the previous day but only for the active campaigns.

Comment: This code works! :) awesome. The new screenshot has the column highlighted for today=30th August 2016. I would only like to do cell fill coloring for the column of the previous day/yesterday=29th August 2016. Can this be incorporated @user3598756

Comment: As per this site rules 1) since I fulfilled your _original_ question please mark my answer as accepted thank you. 2) make a new post for the new issue

Comment: Thanks again. Will post another question

Comment: Could you please look at my second question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239439/select-column-based-on-previous-date-and-perform-cell-fill-color) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239439/select-column-based-on-previous-date-and-perform-cell-fill-color         when you get a moment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try this.

```
Public Sub ChangeCellColors()
  Dim rngTarget As Excel.Range: Set rngTarget = Range("H3")
  Dim rngSource As Excel.Range: Set rngSource = Range("H4")
  Dim rngCell As Excel.Range

  For Each rngCell In Range("B4:B17")
    With rngCell.Interior
      If rngCell.Interior.Color = rngTarget.Interior.Color Then
        .Pattern = rngSource.Interior.Pattern
        .PatternColorIndex = rngSource.Interior.PatternColorIndex
        .Color = rngSource.Interior.Color
        .TintAndShade = rngSource.Interior.TintAndShade
        .PatternTintAndShade = rngSource.Interior.PatternTintAndShade
      End If
    End With
  Next rngCell

  Set rngSource = Nothing
  Set rngTarget = Nothing
  Set rngCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks MJH, this code snippet is almost getting me there. In my working sheet I have the column Today highlighted using(conditional statement and today() function). Would it be possible to automatically select the Yesterday column to perform this cell fill color replacement? Thanks

Comment: Hi MJH, the macro is replacing all the cells in the column "Yesterday" to the color in cell "H4". any ideas?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, sorry, but I don't understand.  What do you mean by "I have the column Today highlighted using(conditional statement and today() function)"? And, are you looking for something more flexible than `Range("B5:B17")`, perhaps because that range will not be static? Regarding the second comment, I was under the impression that's what you wanted.

Comment: @MJM Thanks for your answer, not to be more confusing, I have attached my actual worksheet i.stack.imgur.com/BuiFc.jpg    This worksheet should help me track the progress of any campaign. When I open the spreadsheet based on the date, the particular column gets highlighted. I have used conditional formatting & today() function to achieve this. The next step is to fill cell color for the previous day but only for the active campaigns.

Comment: Thanks, but the new screenshot doesn't help to explain the issues you are having with the code I provided.  That code does do exactly what you asked, i.e. "replace the fill colors of cells in a column 'Yesterday' based on the existing cell fill color". If you've modified it, please provide the exact code you are running, and how it is not working for you. In other words, provide details regarding how the sheet looks before you run the code, the results you expect after the code runs, and the results you are getting instead.

Comment: @MJM I have limited/no experience in coding and hence, I have copy pasted snippets from all over the internet and it looks like a mixed pot. The below snippet worked and the only missing part is to perform the cell fill coloring for the previous day(29th August 2016) column cells.

Comment: I am referring only to the code I posted.  Again, please explain, in detail, the problem you are having with the code I posted, or I cannot help you. If my code is working for you, but you have some other problem, please mark my answer as "Accepted", and create a new Question.

Comment: I used your code and all the selected range of cells were cell color filled with the color of cell H4.

Comment: What do you mean by "selected range of cells"? Please note that my code does not involve the "Selection" object at all.

Comment: The code refers to "B5:B17" and I get as attached. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OZdQ8.jpg

Comment: OK, I think I see it now. In your original question you said "trying to replace the fill colors of cells in a column", which I assumed to mean the entire column. However, now I notice cell G3 in your original screenshot, which says "Replace 'Yesterday' column cell color". So, it seems you don't want the entire range B5:B17 to change color, you want to leave alone the cells B9, B10, B14 because they don't match the color in cell H3.  Is that right?

Comment: @MJM exactly. If you see my 2nd screenshot of my actual working document, the entire scenario or what I'm trying to achieve would be clearer. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. See the revised code above, and please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @MJM beautiful. works! :) Can I run this cell fill color macro each day only on the column which would be Yesterday or PreviousDay? I guess based on the today's date. Essentially, the B5:B17 range in your code would become a dynamic range of column cells?

Comment: Sure.  Give it a try on your own, and if you get stuck, post a new question. In the meantime, if I answered this question, please mark my answer as Accepted.